# The infinitely many solutions of $e^{2z-3} = 5$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have $$e^{2z-3} = 5$$

I'm trying to find ALL the complex numbers that satisfy this but can't get my head around how to do it?

I can solve for z, this gave me $z = {(\ln5 +3)}/2$

But for complex numbers asking for multiple answers this doesn't seem the logical solution?

Any advice would be brilliant

Comment: Take into account that all the logarithms of $5$ are $\ln(5)+2\pi ik$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: note $e^{2\pi i}=1$

Comment: Thank you! so should I substitute in the $e^{(2/pi i)}$ at the beginning and work it through or just use it to find solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{2z-3} = 5$$
Letting $z=x+i\,y:$
$$e^{2x-3}e^{i\,2y}=5$$
Taking the complex logarithm:
$$2x-3+i(2y+2m\pi)=\ln5+i(2n\pi)$$
Equating the real and imaginary parts:
$$x=\frac{3+\ln5}2\; \text{ and }\; y=k\pi$$
I.e., $$z=\frac{3+\ln5}2+i\,k\pi.$$

(Since every step above is reversible, no extraneous solution has been created.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You're almost there. Remember that $f(z) = e^z$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$ and is 1-1 on each horizontal strip $S_a \equiv\{z : a \leq \operatorname{Im} z < a + 2\pi\}$, so if you find one solution you can find all the others.

Your function is a slight modification of this--the factor of $2$ must be taken into account.

Comment: Thank you! so should I substitute in the e(2/pii) at the beginning and work it through or just use it to find solutions?

Comment: When you took the logarithm, you chose a specific value, $\ln 5$. There are infinitely many such values ($\ln 5 + 2\pi i k$), each differing by an integer multiple of the period of the exponential function. That's how you get all of the solutions.